# Springboot unittest when applicationcontext initialize based on environment value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, junit5

I have a working spring boot application and adding unit tests now. I am trying to write a unit test for the Service layer which has two possible handlers. At a time any one of the handlers will be active based on deployment of the service.

My code looks like below.

Config-

```
package com.org.app.configs;

@Configuration
public class DeploymentFactoryManager {
    @Value("${deployment:}")
    private String deploymentEnv;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Bean
    public IDeploymentHandler getDeploymentInterface() throws InvalidConfigException {
        IDeploymentHandler deploymentHandler = null;
        if(deploymentEnv.equalsIgnoreCase("kubernetes")){
            deploymentHandler = ctx.getBean(KubernetesDeployHandler.class);
        }else if(deploymentEnv.equalsIgnoreCase("docker")){
            deploymentHandler =  ctx.getBean(DockerDeployHandler.class);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("Unknown queue type : "+deploymentEnv);
        }
        return deploymentHandler;
    }
}
```

Service-

```
package com.org.app.services;

public List<String> status() throws InvalidConfigException{
        
    @Autowired
    DeploymentFactoryManager deploymentFactoryManager;
        
    public List<String> getStatus(){
        IDeploymentHandler iDeploymentHandler = deploymentFactoryManager.getDeploymentInterface();
        return iDeploymentHandler.list();
    }
```

I am facing an issue while writing unit tests. So far I have already tried with `ReflectionTestUtils` to set the field but it fails with the message `Either target object or target class for the field must be specified.` I tried with `@TestPropertySource` but that also doesn't seem to work. Code doesn't seem unit test friendly.

```
@BeforeAll
    public static void setup(){
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(deploymentFactoryManager, "deploymentEnv", "kubernetes");
    }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated?

Comment: Are you really writing a unit test? If so, you don't need the application context because you would want to test your Service in isolation. Currently, it looks more like an integration test. Could you provide your test class with all of its annotations and the test method itself?

Comment: Yes, I was writing unit tests but my approach was wrong. As you rightly said, application context is not required here.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note: You make your code easier to test if you inject every dependency, like:

```
public IDeploymentHandler getDeploymentInterface( @Value("${deployment:}") String deploymentEnv, ApplicationContext ctx ) throws InvalidConfigException {
```

In general, it's not a good strategy to get beans out of the context; it's the opposite of the Spring idea: tell what u want and don't ask for it.

Comment: `@Beforeeach
 public void setup(){
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(deploymentFactoryManager, "deploymentEnv", "kubernetes");
    }` worked for me.

Comment: +1  for in general, it's not a good strategy to get beans out of the context; it's the opposite of the Spring idea: tell what u want and don't ask for it.  I was new to spring boot.